# How to get suggested followers list by Instagram API in Android

Tags: android, instagram-api

I need to get list of followers of Instagram to whom I can follow in my Android application. Can anyone suggest the API?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Googling gave me this link:

http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by
```

Comment: It returns followers. I need suggest followers to whom I can follow in future if I want. Like suggest friends would be provided in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if this data isn't accessible through the API.  (See their docs: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Instagram's API is generally pretty restrictive, so it's no surprise that fringe functionality you're talking about isn't available to the public.